# How to setup constraint for 2 Labels and One UIImageView in Tableview Cell using storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, constraints

[image: Image Attached]

How to setup constraint for 2 Labels and One UIImageView in Tableview Cell using storyboard?How to setup constraint for 2 Labels and One UIImageView in Tableview Cell using storyboard?

Comment: Please explain your requirement clear as the above question is a vague one

Comment: I want to add proper constraints for Left UIImageView , Two Labels and Right UIImageView , But I dont know how

Answer (score 0):

Try embedding the labels in a vertical UIStackView, then the image and the new UIStackView in a horizontal UIStackView.
Then constraint the last UIStackView to the edges of the cell.
Eventually set the spacing for this two stack views and you are done.